# PHP hooks setting to be called through different classes

Tags: php, oop

I'm going to structure this as best I can. Basically I have a Hook class that works by adding supplied hooks.

An example of this would be:

**`$this->registry->hook->add('HOOK_NAME', 'CLASS_NAME||METHOD_NAME')`**

The hook adding, calling, removing functions work great, now the issue resides when I set the hook in a separate method in a completely different class.

An example of this would be when a user logs in.

The path they take is **`User Controller`** -> **`Form Class`** -> **`Login Process Function`**

Now within this login process function, I'd like to set a hook to be called later to end the session. (Would be added as stated above)

The issue seems to be that it gets set but doesn't stay persistently, if that makes sense?

If anyone is interested, this is what the hook add function looks like:

```
function add($hook, $callback, $params = '') {
        //make sure the hook is defined
        if (!isset($this->hooks[$hook])) {
            $this->hooks[$hook] = array();
        }
        //add the callback to the hook
        $this->hooks[$hook]['callback'] = $callback;
        // add the params if supplied
        if (!empty($params)) {
            $this->hooks[$hook]['params'] = $params;
        }
    }
```

Should I be using magic methods **`__set()`** and **`__get()`** ?

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Do you have multiple hook objects? If so you may want to look up the singleton pattern and use that

Comment: @steven I've checked, it's only the one object that is instantiated throughout, which is weird :(

Comment: I think your code only allows one callback per HOOK_NAME. If you try to set 2 callbacks for the same HOOK_NAME the first one will be overridden. Is that the problem?

Comment: Are you talking about different requests? What Steven asked? Something else? As it currently stands it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @steven that HOOK_NAME was just an example, the hook I'd want to set would look like this `('session_end', 'auth||session_end')`.

Comment: @PeeHaa It seems the hooks are only able to be accessed within the method that calls them, that's the issue. As I'd like to call them globally.